# Grep - how to find lines with at least 3 times a specific number

Tags: regex, bash, grep, binary

I have a file filled with binary strings. Now I need to find the lines with at least three times the number 1 in it. How do I do this using grep?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this thus far? What hasn't worked?

Comment: What does "the number 1" mean in the context of "a binary string"? Please give examples.

Answer (score 2):

Match 1 followed by anything (including an empty string), 3 times:

```
grep -E '(1.*){3}' file
```

`-E` enables Extended regex, otherwise you could use:

```
grep '\(1.*\)\{3\}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
grep '1.*1.*1' file
```

'.*' means any character any number of times including no character. The expression will match no matter how many characters in between, before or after the ones, but will need to have three ones to match.